# @AfterTest method in testNG accept return type,what is the use of reutrn type here

Tags: java, testng

`@Afeter`Test method in `testNG` can able to return object, so here if `@AfterTest` method return something how we can catch this return object for, more idea please refer below code

```
      @AfterTest
      public String afterTest(){
        return "After test method get executed";
        }
```

How user can catch the returned Object, which is return by the @AfterTest method, if we can not able to catch the return object then what is the use of return something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **do** some operation **after** the Test **Execution**, please use **TestNG listener** instead of this return type.

**ITestListener** has following methods to utilize,

1. OnStart
2. onTestSuccess
3. onTestFailure
4. onTestSkipped
5. onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage
6. onFinish

**No way to get the return string.**

Comment: Thank you for reply, here i want to know what is the use of return type

Answer (score 0):

> `@AfterTest` method return something how we can catch this return
> object

Let's see the below example to understand this thing,

**Code**:

```
    public class ClassTestNG {

    int test;

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println("test value in first test: " + test);
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        int newValue = increaseValue();
        System.out.println("test vale in second test: " + newValue);
    }

    @AfterTest
    public int increaseValue() {
        int c = test + 3;
        return c;
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
test value in first test: 0
test value in second test: 3
```

- I want to call `increaseValue` method after all my tests as well I want to reuse the same method wherever it's required. So I tagged the method under `@AfterTest` tag also I called it inside of `secondTest`
- In real time if there is any piece of code that needs to be executed after all your tests and should return a result for further execution you can use like this.

Comment: Thank you for reply, For initialize or increment the value of int there is no need of return we can just say test++,system can initialize the test varible and we can able to use the test variable with initialize value

Comment: Purpose of example is to say how to use return method in `AfterTest` tag. I am not saying for increment purpose. Let's say there is a return type method and you want to execute that using `AfterTest` tag and the same method you can call wherever it's required to reuse that.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for reply and sorry for delay, I get some idea why we use the return type in testng